# How to add gradient on the textInput using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown, gradient

I have textInput field on which I want to apply the gradient on all 4 sides just like border on any box.
The gradient does apply partially but it shows a weird thick upper border and it does even not show it on all 4 sides of the box.
Also, all other sides are without a gradient.
The code I am trying is:

```
<View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
  <Text
    style={[
      styles.firstNameLabel,
      firstNameError ? styles.errorColor : styles.inputLabelColor,
    ]}
  >
    First Name
  </Text>
  <LinearGradientView
     style={{ borderRadius: 5 }}
     colors={['rgba(9, 95, 216, 1)', 'rgba(128, 69, 224, 1)']}
     end={{
       x: 1.5,
       y: 2,
     }}
     start={{
       x: 1.2,
       y: 1.5,
     }}
   >
   <View
     style={{
       paddingHorizontal: 0,
       paddingVertical: 0,
       flex: 1,
       padding: 3,
     }}
   >
      <TextInput
        style={styles.firstNameInputField}
        mode="outlined"
        theme={{
          colors: {
            text: '#4D4D4D',
            primary: 'transparent',
          },
          roundness: 5,
        }}
        selectionColor="#095FD8FF"
        outlineColor="#D7D7D7"
      />
    </View>
  </LinearGradientView>
</View>
```

This is a problematic image:
[image: This is a problematic image]

This is what is needed
[image: This is what is needed]

Comment: This seems fun. Imma give a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect you want you could just give the LinearGradient some padding to act as the borderWidth:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {LinearGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient'

export default function App() {
  const firstNameError = null;
  return (
    <View style={{ padding:8,marginBottom: 20 }}>
  <Text
    style={[
      styles.firstNameLabel,
      firstNameError ? styles.errorColor : styles.inputLabelColor,
    ]}
  >
    First Name
  </Text>
  <LinearGradient
     style={{ borderRadius: 5,padding:2 }}
     colors={['rgba(9, 95, 216, 1)', 'rgba(128, 69, 224, 1)']}
     end={{
       x: 1.5,
       y: 2,
     }}
     start={{
       x: 1.2,
       y: 1.5,
     }}
   >
   <View
     style={{
       paddingHorizontal: 0,
       paddingVertical: 0,
       flex: 1,
       padding: 3,
     }}
   >
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        mode="outlined"
        theme={{
          colors: {
            text: '#4D4D4D',
            primary: 'transparent',
          },
          roundness: 5,
        }}
        selectionColor="#095FD8FF"
        outlineColor="#D7D7D7"
      />
    </View>
  </LinearGradient>
</View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor:'white'
  },
});
```

Comment: Never thought of this approach! Gonna try in the app but I am accepting the answer as it is almost what I wanted :) Martese Rocked :D Thanks Man :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398168/how-we-can-give-auto-height-to-flatlist-based-on-its-list-items-content-in-react/ Any best practices you can refer me to? Thanks!