# How we can give auto height to FlatList based on its list items content in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using FlatList in my component which is working fine. All is wanted is that my entire screen should have an automatic height to it and FlatList contents never does out of the screen height.

Also, the height of FlatList should be changed based on content/items in it rather than giving any fixed height.

How I can be acheived both cases like automatic screen height and auto height of FlatList content?

Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  useWindowDimensions,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient as LinearGradientView } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { ActivityIndicator, ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useIsFocused, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Svg, { Path } from 'react-native-svg';
import { BASE_GRADIENT_HEAVY } from '../rooms/Background';
import { useResolution } from '../browse/useResolution';
import { OnboardingNavigationProp } from '../navigation/LinkingConfiguration';
import { LIGHT_THEME } from '../Theme';
import { OnboardingBack } from './OnboardingBack';
import {
  useOnboardingYearsOfExperiencePage,
  useOnboardingYearsOfExperienceSubmit,
} from './useOnboardingYearsOfExperiencePage';

export function OnboardingYearsOfExperience({ route }: { route?: any }) {
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const { top: safeAreaTop } = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState<{ id: string }>();
  const [role_id, setRoleId] = useState<number>();
  const { navigate } =
    useNavigation<OnboardingNavigationProp<'OnboardingConfirmAllDetails'>>();

  const parentUrl = route?.params.result.onboarding._links;
  const initialUrl = parentUrl.onboarding_years_of_experience.href;
  const onboardingUrl = parentUrl.self.href;

  useEffect(() => {
    setRoleId(route?.params.role_id);
  }, []);

  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const { contentType } = useResolution();

  const {
    data: result,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useOnboardingYearsOfExperiencePage(initialUrl, contentType, role_id, {
    enabled: isFocused,
    notifyOnChangeProps: ['data', 'isLoading', 'error'],
  });

  const {
    mutateAsync: updateYearsOfExperience,
    isLoading: isUpdatingYearsOfExperience,
    error: yearsOfExperienceUpdateError,
  } = useOnboardingYearsOfExperienceSubmit(onboardingUrl);

  const Arrow = ({ style }: { style: object }) => {
    return (
      <Svg width="7" height="11" viewBox="0 0 7 11" fill="none" style={style}>
        <Path
          d="M6.28711 5.53931C6.28711 5.31649 6.19783 5.12476 6.02452 4.95376L1.9911 1.07251C1.85455 0.937781 1.68649 0.865234 1.48692 0.865234C1.07728 0.865234 0.751664 1.18651 0.751664 1.58552C0.751664 1.78243 0.830441 1.96898 0.977493 2.11407L4.54875 5.53413L0.977492 8.95937C0.835692 9.10446 0.751663 9.28583 0.751662 9.48792C0.751662 9.88693 1.07728 10.2082 1.48692 10.2082C1.68649 10.2082 1.85455 10.1357 1.99635 10.0009L6.02452 6.11968C6.20308 5.93832 6.28711 5.75695 6.28711 5.53931Z"
          fill="#4D4D4D"
        />
      </Svg>
    );
  };

  const Item = ({
    item,
    onPress,
  }: {
    item?: { id: string; title: string };
    onPress: () => void;
  }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <Text
        style={{
          color: '#4D4D4D',
          fontFamily: 'Inter_400Regular',
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontWeight: '400',
          fontSize: 16,
          lineHeight: 32,
          padding: 3,
          margin: 2,
        }}
      >
        {item?.title}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: { id: string; title: string } }) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor:
              selectedId?.id === item?.id ? '#F2F2F2' : 'transparent',
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ width: '90%' }}>
            <Item
              item={item}
              onPress={() => {
                setSelectedId({ id: item.id });
                updateYearsOfExperience({ id: item.id, role_id })
                  .then((result) => {
                    navigate('Onboarding', {
                      screen: 'OnboardingConfirmAllDetails',
                      params: { result },
                    });
                  })
                  .catch(() => {});
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ width: '10%' }}>
            <Arrow style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 16, right: 10 }} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={LIGHT_THEME}>
      <View style={{ height: safeAreaTop }} />
      <View style={styles.topHeader}>
        <LinearGradientView
          {...BASE_GRADIENT_HEAVY}
          style={[styles.gradiantStyle]}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            marginHorizontal: 'auto',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            height: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <OnboardingBack
            style={{
              left: -10,
            }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.topHeadline}>
            How many years of experience do you have?
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.middleHeadline}>
            Jump-start the conversation by sharing your years of experience
            within healthcare.
          </Text>
          {isLoading || isUpdatingYearsOfExperience ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          ) : (
            <SafeAreaView>
              <FlatList
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                data={Object.values(
                  result!['years_of_experiences']['years_of_experiences_list']
                )}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                extraData={selectedId}
                style={{
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderStyle: 'solid',
                  borderColor: '#D7D7D7',
                  borderRadius: 5,
                  padding: 12,
                  height: '27%',
                }}
                ListEmptyComponent={
                  <View>
                    <Text>No data found</Text>
                  </View>
                }
              />
            </SafeAreaView>
          )}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  innerContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 18,
  },

  topHeader: {
    backgroundColor: '#e5dede',
    padding: 0,
    width: '100%',
  },

  topHeadline: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'CircularStd_Medium',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#222222',
    marginTop: 40.6,
    marginBottom: 14.6,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    lineHeight: 32,
  },

  middleHeadline: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: 'Inter_400Regular',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: '400',
    lineHeight: 24,
    color: '#4D4D4D',
    marginBottom: 30,
  },

  gradiantStyle: {
    width: 248.4,
    height: 4.71,
  },
});
```

Comment: just 1 doubt , what if suppose the height of flatlist with all items exceed device height? whats the ideal behavior

Comment: Yeah, that's my point too. I do not want that to happen on the screen. First, the screen size should get adjusted automatically (we do not need to provide any height to screen - don't know if I am right about it - please correct me) and 2ndly, if list contains 5 items the Flatlist should show border within 5 items only. If it exceed the screen size, we will not allow that to happen but add some scroll etc. also some paddingbottom to edges do not touch the end of screen. Makes sense?

Comment: So you only want the flatlist to take up the exact amount of space it needs to, but to never take on more space than the screen width?

Comment: Yes that's correct and thank you. with more items than screen width, scroll will be applied to flat list automatically.

Answer (score 2):

add the following style to your flatList =>

style={{maxHeight:'what ever you want',flexGrow:0}}

Comment: I do not want to explicitly give it any height.

Comment: ok just use flexGrow:0

Comment: Alone this style does not work. Thanks for the answer but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 40, paddingVertical: 100, backgroundColor: '#333' }}>
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
    <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'aqua' }}>
      <Text>Here is some content</Text>
    </View>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'fuchsia' }}
        data={ data }
        renderItem={ ({ item }) => <Item item={ item } /> }
      />
    <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'lime' }}>
      <Text>Here is some other content</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

In the following snack, change the number passed to createData. Be sure to test on iOS or Android as the web view will continue to push down the page.

https://snack.expo.dev/T17qc65CR